# PHP mysql PDO - Completely new - Advice and explanation needed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[Tutorial I'm following with all the code I'm using](http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/)

Ok, question is pretty simple: I'm just a snippet recycler but I can learn fast if someone can point me in the right direction.

I tried various lectures around but these are pretty confused for me.

I'm running this little cms in my localhost and I need to convert mysql queries to PDO, can someone explain me exactly what this code is doing and how I can convert it to the not deprecated PDO?

```
public static function getById( $id ) {
 $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
 $sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles WHERE id = :id";
 $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
 $st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
 $st->execute();
 $row = $st->fetch();
 $conn = null;
 if ( $row ) return new Article( $row );}
```

It's just one of the snippets that connects to the  database and I can intuitively understand what is doing, I have basic knowledge of SQL and PHP syntax, but I need more friendly help.

[My GitHub repo for this tutorial, if someone want to help me more directly](https://github.com/Flygohr/simple-php-cms)

Thank you in advice!

Here's the *error* message:

```
Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql\classes\Article.php on line 105
```

The code in question is

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
            ORDER BY " . mysql_real_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows"; // this is line 105
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();
    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $article = new Article( $row );
      $list[] = $article;
    }
    // Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
  }
```

Comment: Post your error too!!!

Comment: The error is simple and it's not a **real** error, It's just the deprecation handler that tells me to use PDO and I really want, I don't want to learn PHP in some outdated way and keep using it 'till I can

Comment: There's a version of PDO that raises "deprecated warnings"? I don't think so.... Please post the _exact_ message you get.

Comment: I've added what I'm seing on my screen when I load the page to the question, point is that I'm using mysql in the code and I now want to switch to PDO

Comment: Around line 105 in Article.php do what you've already demonstrated in the snippet you've posted. Instead of escaping/encoding the parameter and than putting it _into_ the query string, build a prepared statement with a parameter placeholder, bind the parameter to the variable holding the param.value and then execute the statement.

Comment: Well @VolkerK, do you have time to explain me what does this mean? Your answer is clear anyway and I can now try to search more specific documentation, but if you can help me I'll be very happy and I'll learned something new fast. Is this 'deprecation' active only around line 105?

Comment: I've added the code of the method around line 105 of Article.php from your git repository. PHP complains about the use of mysql_real_escape_string - because it's deprecated. Even it it wasn't the code would be wrong. Never mix mysql_* function with PDO, nor mysqli and PDO - each API provides its own mechanism to sanitize the parameters.

Comment: But there's another problem with this query. Your ORDER BY clause is supposed to work on a field identifier not on a payload parameter. But the escape functions/method and statement placeholders are not desinged to work on identifiers (and even less on options such as `DESC`). Rule of thumb: If you can put the parameter in single-quotes in the query string it will work with escape_string/quote or parameter placeholder; otherwise it probably won't work (as intended)

Comment: Ok, I understend what deprecation is and what is being deprecated..what I do not understand are all those words like _escaping/encoding_, _bind_, _payload parameter_ and so on..I'm sorry, I'm really just starting coding something more than a phpinfo() in PHP

Comment: maybe interesting? [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). Also: [PHP Database Access: Are You Doing It Correctly?](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)